# What to do if I am trying to pull data from my local host and my IP denies it?

Tags: java, android

what do if I have done Json declaration and other parts as well and at the very end when I want to extract data from my local host my IP

[image]

```
I/System.out: Connection to http://192.168.137.10 refused
```

Comment: The first questions you should ask yourself are: Is that really your IP? Why don't use "127.0.0.1"? Do you have your server running? Is there a firewall blocking your port?...

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message - is there actually something running on that ip?

Comment: well IP was right and firewall was on I switched it off, but still can't the result that I want :(

Comment: I am trying to connect & compile thru my Huawei device to localhost